# android - locale notification, need to dump cache

Tags: android, caching, notifications, broadcastreceiver

We are localizing our app to be able to easily switch between languages. Everything works nicely except for some cached values that are actually in navigation. We have two options:

1. completely restart app on language change - in this case I need a notification and force restart
2. just load new strings into the table - in this case it will require to replace string values and rbuild custom navigation state.

IN both cases we need a way to find out when language switches. Is there an intent we can listen to? If yes could you please advise on which one? I am thinking to go with a broadcast receiver. I am just not sure which intent action it is. In below example what is the SOME_ACTION value?

Thanks in advance.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.v1.application.notifications.LanguageChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SOME_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: [ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED)

Comment: thank you it probably is. However we solved the issue differently. We reload navigation and inspect if changes are made instead. Also we only work with resource Ids now instead of with strings. This way once the resorrces change, we pull updated titles.Pretty cool, hah? :)

Comment: What's the answer? I see only a constant string definition.

Comment: Hi @dropsOfJupiter how did you fix some getResources are caching the content it stays in the old locale.