# Change strings in notification bar after a change in the locale

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I have few string.xml files for different languages, and when I change my locale everything is okey all my labels in my activity are changed except the one in the notification.

Is there anything like a 'refresh' command to send to the notification? to refresh the strings?

Comment: See related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8691

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported number of times on different forums.  Probably the most appropriate solutions/workaround can be found here:
[android - locale notification, need to dump cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776313/android-locale-notification-need-to-dump-cache)

Kind regards,
Bo